# Ignoring newline character while reading csv file with mutiple delimiters in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data that contains '|' as separator but also every row have newline separator which is not relevant. It is like:

```
 - CONTRSTART|"""Contract End Date"""CONTR1END:/BI0/OICONTR1END|"""Contract End Re
ason"""/BIC/ZUCCANCRS:/BIC/OIZUCCANCRS|"""Disconnection Date"""UC_DIDATE:/BI0/O
IUC_DIDATE|"""Dunning Procedure"""CADUNN_PRC:/BI0/OICADUNN_PRC|"""Dunning Block
 Reason"""CADUNN_BLO:/BI0/OICADUNN_BLO
4100006664||00000000|00000000|20130405|20130917|220000081194|20130405|20130903|
00000000|00000000||00000000||
4100012973||00000000|00000000|20130409|20130430|220000145601|20130401|20130401|
```

If you notice, the first line ends at 'Re' and next line begins with 'ason'. Same with the other rows. The rows are also separated by '/n' so I cannot ignore all these newline characters. Is there a way to ignore these specific newline separator while reading it in Python?

Comment: If that's how your data was entered, consider reentering it.

Comment: how would you have python make the distinction between a newline which is the seperation between records, and a newline within a value?

Comment: I did not notice this before your question.. so for separation of rows. is also '/n' separated and there are few unwanted '/n' separators. Is there a way to ignore these specific '/n ' separators..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use dropna method,

```
#first read your in put
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep='|')
#then ignore your new line
df=df.dropna()
```

If you want something different add a comment.:)

Comment: reading it as above is giving multiple columns not properly assigned.

Comment: No.. i have updated the question,.. few newline separators are not right and are placed inside the rows..